# How binding array strings to DataGridView (WinForms) with use settings DataSource,DataPropertyName?

Tags: c#, winforms

How use PropertyName for binding array strings with DataGridView?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { DataPropertyName = "{}" });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new [] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
}
```

Comment: Use `var files = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)).GetFiles();`. Set `.AutoGenerateColumns = false`. Pick one of the properties of FileInfo as the `DataPropertyName`. Or leave `.AutoGenerateColumns = true`, without adding any Column, to show all properties.

Comment: What does FileInfo have to do with my code?
An array of strings is available. Note the array of strings, not the FileInfo array. Only an array of strings.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` instead of `Directory.GetFiles()`. So you have properties to bind.

Comment: Excuse me. I'm not interested in files.
I am particularly interested in the output of an array of strings. I have repeatedly searched for a solution to my problem on Google. Everywhere I see a solution in Your way. But in General, I don't see how to assign an array of strings.
To be precise, I'm changing my question
to:
How binding array strings to DataGridView (WinForms) with use settings DataSource,DataPropertyName?

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
        }

Comment: E.g., `var files = Directory.GetFiles("Some Path").Select(f => new { FileName = f }).ToList();`. Now, `DataPropertyName = "FileName"`, since the anonymous object is generated with a property named `FileName` and you can set the DGV's `.DataSource = files`. -- A simple `string` object has no property name, the value used is its length.

Comment: _”How use PropertyName for binding array strings with DataGridView?”_ … Well … you need a “property” to bind it to. An “object” array of string’s doesn’t have any “properties” other than what Jimi notes… its “length.” Therefore, the grid is going to display 3,3,5,4. The string length.

Comment: You need to use a “Class” that has a property to use the grids `DataPropertyName`. Create a simple class “T” with a `string` “property”… call that property “TheProperty” then make an array or list of “T” objects, then use that array/list as a data source to the grid. THEN you will have a `DataPropertyName` to bind the column to… namely `TheProperty`.

Comment: This method (linq. select(s=>new{name=s});) I know. I always do.
I am interested in the method of binding to an array of strings. I am interested for the Outlook in programming. I think You would also be interested in how to do this..
in WPF, I can bind a DataGrid using the name " {Binding}", without specifying the name of the array element property. This method works in WPF. I want to be able to do the same in WinForms